# how to return "localhost" from InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() in docker container

Tags: java, docker, dns, localhost, containers

In my docker container (Java application), the call to `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` returns the same name we gave in `docker run --name 'myserver'`.

Is there a way to let `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()` return "localhost" in Java code inside the docker container?

My /etc/hosts in the docker container looks like this:

`127.0.0.1   localhost
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
<snip>
172.17.0.5  myserver`

Comment: If you insist that it has to be localhost, why not just hard code it?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use this sample code to validate the same...

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
public class Util {
public static String getHostName() {
    String hostName = "";
    try {
        InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        hostName = inetAddress.getHostName();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

    }
    return hostName;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getHostName());
}
```

}

Let's assume that you are running a docker container in a Box name `BOX1`

and the docker containerId  = 164f1347533a...

This will print `164f1347533a` as the Hostname.

To get `BOX1`, you will have to pass --hostname=BOX1 in the startup command.

Comment: What I was looking for was opposite. My code already returned the docker container name (id or a given name), but I wanted to return "localhost" or it's IP (127.0.0.1). It turns out this is actually implementation dependent, for example behaves differently on MacOS and Linux. The only way to be sure seems to call `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces` and loop through the interface to use either the loopback (localhost) or the real ipv4 address and its name.

Comment: If so, then why not hard code it as suggested by @shoan ?

Comment: We actually had cases for both "localhost" and outgoing host address. We refactored the code eventually and handled both.